# Algorithm for auto-indenting brackets in code

Tags: c#, winforms, auto-indent

im working on a code-editor (WinForms) and i want to know how to do function of { and } specifically the auto-indention using brackets (open and close) like in actual code editor .

> ---|> { and }

like this 1:

[image]

Editor was a richtextbox named rtb.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking for a set of requirements ... or code samples

Comment: code sample sir @lexu

Comment: I presume, you can workout a recursive function which initiate when user close the last closed curly bracket and workout until you find a open curly bracket. And appending tabs/required indentation on each stage of iteration.

Comment: @nair yes sir ... thats what i want . like tabbing all text inside { }

Comment: Can you show us what code you have written so far?

Comment: @BrianRogers sorry sir i got no code so far for indention only for highlighting :/

Comment: @Elegiac: did you take a look at the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968057/free-open-source-code-editor-ui-control-for-net

Comment: @saravanan i do but thats not what i needed sir i need codes for indention .

Comment: did you checkout the SelectionIndent property in richtextbox: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionindent.aspx

Comment: @Elegiac you are sure you wane do this? After trying to solve your problem i found multiple things that need to be circuit for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520472/keydown-recognizes-the-left-and-right-directional-arrow-keys-but-not-up-and-dow)

Comment: yes pls help mesir @WiiMaxx

Comment: i willwait sir @WiiMaxx really thanks for that :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please read the following texts before reading and using codes:**

1. *I've not enough time for writing better codes. I have only tried to write **a sample** for you.*
2. *I have only written the codes in a simple way, **not in OOP**.*
3. *You can improve the codes with using **Enums**, **Properties**, **Classes** and **other things of OOP**.*
4. *You can improve the **logic of the codes**; and you can use **Multi-Threading for achieve to better performance**.*
5. *This sample **isn't thorough**. I has only implemented an **Auto-Indention example for "semicolon (;)" character**.*

I should say some *tips* for using the codes:

1. **rtbCodes** is the *name of the RichTextBox control* on the form in the sample project.
2. **frmCodeEditor** is the *name of the form* in the sample project.

You can download the sample project from the following addresses:

[4Shared -> Auto-Indention for Code Editor](http://www.4shared.com/zip/2vzml1-A/Auto-Indention_for_Code_Editor.html)

[SendSpace -> Auto-Indention for Code Editor](http://www.sendspace.com/file/7jkbjh)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class frmCodeEditor : Form
    {
        char[] chrTracingKeyChars = new char[] { ';', '}', '\n' };
        char[] chrCheckingKeyChars = new char[] { '{', '(' };
        Point ptCurrentCharPosition;
        bool bolCheckCalling = false;
        int intInitialCursorPosition = 0;
        int intRemainingCharsOfInitialText = 0;
        int intNextCharIndex = 0;
        int intPrevCharIndex = 0;

        public frmCodeEditor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AutoIndention(rtbCodes);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implements Auto-Indention.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rtb">A RichTextBox control</param>
        private void AutoIndention(RichTextBox rtb)
        {
            char chrLastChar = GetChar(rtb);

            if (chrLastChar == chrTracingKeyChars[0])
            {
                intRemainingCharsOfInitialText = rtb.TextLength - rtb.SelectionStart;
                intInitialCursorPosition = rtb.SelectionStart;
                ImplementIndentionForSemicolon(rtb);
            }
            else if (chrLastChar == chrTracingKeyChars[1])
            {
                ImplementIndentionForRightCurlyBracket(rtb);
            }
            else if (chrLastChar == chrTracingKeyChars[2])
            {
                ImplementIndentionForNewLineCharacter(rtb);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies current char based on the cursor position.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rtb">A RichTextBox control</param>
        /// <returns>Returns a char.</returns>
        private char GetChar(RichTextBox rtb)
        {
            return GetChar(rtb.SelectionStart, rtb);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies a char based on the specified index.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="intCharIndex">A char index</param>
        /// <param name="rtb">A RichTextBox control</param>
        /// <returns>Returns a char.</returns>
        private char GetChar(int intCharIndex, RichTextBox rtb)
        {
            if (intCharIndex != rtb.TextLength)
            {
                ptCurrentCharPosition = rtb.GetPositionFromCharIndex(intCharIndex - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                ptCurrentCharPosition = rtb.GetPositionFromCharIndex(intCharIndex);
            }
            return rtb.GetCharFromPosition(ptCurrentCharPosition);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies current line number based on the cursor position.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rtb">A RichTextBox control</param>
        /// <returns>Returns the line number.</returns>
        private int GetLineNumber(RichTextBox rtb)
        {
            return GetLineNumber(rtb.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine(), rtb);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies the line number based on the specified index.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="intCharIndex">A char index</param>
        /// <param name="rtb">A RichTextBox control</param>
        /// <returns>Returns the line number.</returns>
        private int GetLineNumber(int intCharIndex, RichTextBox rtb)
        {
            return rtb.GetLineFromCharIndex(intCharIndex);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implements indention for semicolon ";" character.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rtb">A RichTextBox control</param>
        private void ImplementIndentionForSemicolon(RichTextBox rtb)
        {
            Dictionary<char, int> dicResult = IsExistCheckingKeyChars(rtb);
            if (dicResult[chrCheckingKeyChars[0]] != -1)
            {
                int intIndentionLevel = CheckingIndentionLevel(dicResult[chrCheckingKeyChars[0]], rtb);
                ImplementIndention(dicResult[chrCheckingKeyChars[0]], intIndentionLevel, rtb);
            }
        }

        private void ImplementIndentionForRightCurlyBracket(RichTextBox rtb)
        {

        }

        private void ImplementIndentionForNewLineCharacter(RichTextBox rtb)
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks current and previous lines for finding key-chars.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rtb">A RichTextBox control</param>
        /// <param name="bolSearchCurrentLine">The search state</param>
        /// <returns>Returns first occurrences of key-chars before current char.</returns>
        private Dictionary<char, int> IsExistCheckingKeyChars(RichTextBox rtb, bool bolSearchCurrentLine = false)
        {
            GetChar(rtb);

            Dictionary<char, int> dicCheckingKeyCharsIndexes = new Dictionary<char, int>();
            for (int intCntr = 0; intCntr < chrCheckingKeyChars.Length; intCntr++)
            {
                dicCheckingKeyCharsIndexes.Add(chrCheckingKeyChars[intCntr], 0);
            }

            for (int intCntr = 0; intCntr < chrCheckingKeyChars.Length; intCntr++)
            {
                int intFirstIndexForChecking = 0;
                int intLastIndexForChecking = 0;
                for (int intLineCounter = GetLineNumber(rtb); intLineCounter >= 0; intLineCounter--)
                {
                    if (intLineCounter == GetLineNumber(rtb))
                    {
                        intLastIndexForChecking = rtb.GetCharIndexFromPosition(ptCurrentCharPosition);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        intLastIndexForChecking = intFirstIndexForChecking - 1;
                    }
                    intFirstIndexForChecking = rtb.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(intLineCounter);

                    try
                    {
                        dicCheckingKeyCharsIndexes[chrCheckingKeyChars[intCntr]] = rtb.Find(chrCheckingKeyChars[intCntr].ToString(), intFirstIndexForChecking,
                            rtb.GetCharIndexFromPosition(ptCurrentCharPosition), RichTextBoxFinds.NoHighlight | RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                        if (dicCheckingKeyCharsIndexes[chrCheckingKeyChars[intCntr]] != -1)
                        {
                            do
                            {
                                if (rtb.Find(chrCheckingKeyChars[intCntr].ToString(), intFirstIndexForChecking, rtb.GetCharIndexFromPosition(ptCurrentCharPosition),
                                    RichTextBoxFinds.NoHighlight | RichTextBoxFinds.None) != -1)
                                {
                                    dicCheckingKeyCharsIndexes[chrCheckingKeyChars[intCntr]] = rtb.Find(chrCheckingKeyChars[intCntr].ToString(), intFirstIndexForChecking,
                                        rtb.GetCharIndexFromPosition(ptCurrentCharPosition), RichTextBoxFinds.NoHighlight | RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                                }
                                intFirstIndexForChecking++;
                            } while (intFirstIndexForChecking != rtb.GetCharIndexFromPosition(ptCurrentCharPosition));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        dicCheckingKeyCharsIndexes[chrCheckingKeyChars[intCntr]] = -1;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (bolSearchCurrentLine)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return dicCheckingKeyCharsIndexes;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks a line for calculating its indention level.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="intCharIndex">A char index</param>
        /// <param name="rtb">A RichTextBox control</param>
        /// <returns>Returns indention level of the line.</returns>
        private int CheckingIndentionLevel(int intCharIndex, RichTextBox rtb)
        {
            int intLineNumber = GetLineNumber(intCharIndex, rtb);
            int intIndentionLevelNumber = 0;

            intCharIndex = rtb.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(intLineNumber);
            char chrChar = GetChar(intCharIndex, rtb);
            if (chrChar == '\n')
            {
                chrChar = GetChar(++intCharIndex, rtb);
            }

            if (chrChar != ' ')
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                int intSpaceCntr = 0;
                while(chrChar == ' ')
                {
                    chrChar = GetChar(++intCharIndex, rtb);
                    if (chrChar == ' ')
                    {
                        intSpaceCntr++;
                    }

                    if (intSpaceCntr % 4 == 0 && intSpaceCntr != 0)
                    {
                        intIndentionLevelNumber++;
                        intSpaceCntr = 0;
                    }
                }

                if (intSpaceCntr % 4 != 0)
                {
                    intIndentionLevelNumber++;
                }
            }

            return intIndentionLevelNumber;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implements Indention to the codes
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="intCharIndex">A char index</param>
        /// <param name="intIndentionLevel">The number of indention level</param>
        /// <param name="rtb">A RichTextBox control</param>
        private void ImplementIndention(int intCharIndex, int intIndentionLevel, RichTextBox rtb)
        {
            intNextCharIndex = intCharIndex;

            intPrevCharIndex = intCharIndex;
            int intKeyCharsNumberInLine = 1;
            int intCurrentLineNumber = GetLineNumber(rtb);
            int intKeyCharLineNumber = GetLineNumber(intNextCharIndex, rtb);
            string[] strLinesTexts;
            Dictionary<char, int> dicResult;

            do
            {
                rtb.SelectionStart = intPrevCharIndex;
                dicResult = IsExistCheckingKeyChars(rtb);
                if (dicResult[chrCheckingKeyChars[0]] != -1)
                {
                    intKeyCharsNumberInLine++;
                    intPrevCharIndex = dicResult[chrCheckingKeyChars[0]];
                }
            } while (dicResult[chrCheckingKeyChars[0]] != -1);

            if (!bolCheckCalling)
            {
                if (intCurrentLineNumber == intKeyCharLineNumber)
                {
                    for (int intCntr = 1; intCntr <= intKeyCharsNumberInLine; intCntr++)
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            rtb.SelectionStart = intPrevCharIndex;
                            dicResult = IsExistCheckingKeyChars(rtb, true);
                            if (dicResult[chrCheckingKeyChars[0]] != -1)
                            {

                                intPrevCharIndex = dicResult[chrCheckingKeyChars[0]];
                            }
                        } while (dicResult[chrCheckingKeyChars[0]] != -1);

                        bolCheckCalling = true;
                        ImplementIndention(intPrevCharIndex, rtb);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }

            bolCheckCalling = false;
            rtb.SelectionStart = intNextCharIndex;
            rtb.SelectionLength = 1;
            rtb.SelectedText = "\n" + rtb.SelectedText;
            intCurrentLineNumber = GetLineNumber(rtb);

            strLinesTexts = rtb.Lines;
            strLinesTexts[intCurrentLineNumber] = strLinesTexts[intCurrentLineNumber].Trim();

            for (int intIndentionCntr = 1; intIndentionCntr <= intIndentionLevel; intIndentionCntr++)
            {
                for (int intSpaceCntr = 1; intSpaceCntr <= 4; intSpaceCntr++)
                {
                    strLinesTexts[intCurrentLineNumber] = ' ' + strLinesTexts[intCurrentLineNumber];
                }
            }
            rtb.Lines = strLinesTexts;

            rtb.SelectionStart = intNextCharIndex + ((intIndentionLevel * 4) + 1);
            intNextCharIndex = rtb.SelectionStart;
            rtb.SelectionLength = 1;
            rtb.SelectedText = rtb.SelectedText + "\n";
            intCurrentLineNumber = GetLineNumber(rtb);

            strLinesTexts = rtb.Lines;
            strLinesTexts[intCurrentLineNumber] = strLinesTexts[intCurrentLineNumber].Trim();

            for (int intIndentionCntr = 1; intIndentionCntr <= intIndentionLevel + 1; intIndentionCntr++)
            {
                for (int intSpaceCntr = 1; intSpaceCntr <= 4; intSpaceCntr++)
                {
                    strLinesTexts[intCurrentLineNumber] = ' ' + strLinesTexts[intCurrentLineNumber];
                }
            }
            rtb.Lines = strLinesTexts;
            rtb.SelectionStart = intInitialCursorPosition + ((rtb.TextLength - intInitialCursorPosition) - intRemainingCharsOfInitialText);
            intNextCharIndex = rtb.SelectionStart;
            intPrevCharIndex = intNextCharIndex;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implements Indention to the codes
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="intCharIndex">A char index</param>
        /// <param name="rtb">A RichTextBox control</param>
        private void ImplementIndention(int intCharIndex, RichTextBox rtb)
        {
            int intIndentionLevel = CheckingIndentionLevel(intCharIndex, rtb);
            ImplementIndention(intCharIndex, intIndentionLevel, rtb);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that this sample codes can help you.

**Please update and share codes, if you improve them.**

Comment: what can i say . a lot of effort and time lend for this script . ill remember and do all those words ... thanks a lot sir! such an awesome script more power! :) GodBless ......

Answer (score 5):

ok my solution is buggy but it's enough that you get the idea of how it works

my result:

```
{
        {
                {
                        }
                }
        }
```

and here my Code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool FLAG_Selftimer = false;
    private bool FLAG_KeyPressed = false;
    private int pos = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rtb = sender as RichTextBox;
        var point = rtb.SelectionStart;

        if (!FLAG_Selftimer)
        {
            rtb.Text = ReGenerateRTBText(rtb.Text);
            FLAG_KeyPressed = false;
        }
        else
        {
            point ++;
            FLAG_Selftimer = false;
        }

        rtb.SelectionStart = point;
    }



    private string ReGenerateRTBText(string Text)
    {
        string[] text = Regex.Split(Text,"\n");

        int lvl = 0;
        string newString = "";
        foreach (string line in text)
        {
            line.TrimStart(' ');
            newString += indentation(lvl) + line.TrimStart(' ') + "\n";
            if (line.Contains("{"))
                lvl++;
            if (line.Contains("}"))
                lvl--;
        }

        FLAG_Selftimer = true;
        return (!FLAG_KeyPressed) ? newString : newString.TrimEnd('\n');
    }

    private string indentation(int IndentLevel)
    {
        string space = "";
        if(IndentLevel>0)
            for (int lvl = 0; lvl < IndentLevel; lvl++)
            {
                    space += " ".PadLeft(8);
            }

        return space;
    }

    private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        FLAG_KeyPressed = true;
    }
}
```

i hope this will help you

Comment: +1 for the help sir . even though it has bug when i type text and i press space but its ok i get the idea^^ after a week without better answer ill accept this . thanks a lot for the help!!!

Comment: @Elegiac you will need some logic for the courser position (`rtb.SelectionStart`) and some Key's aren't raise the `KeyPressEvent` which also provides some trouble it's a really tricky problem :-)

Comment: noted sir . hope i can finish this before deadline or im dead :/